Merging multiple audios to a video
I'm a total beginner with FFmpeg and I wanted to know if there's any way to merge multiple audio files and a video. I guess the final file would be MKV.
I was able to do it with only one audio file yesterday using:
ffmpeg -i input_aud.mp4 -i input_vid.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4

But I have no idea if there's any way to do it with multiple audio files.

ffmpeg -i vid -i aud1 -i aud2 -i aud3 -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -c copy out.mkv

Assume that you have one video file (input_vid.mp4) and two audio files (input_aud_1.mp4 and input_aud_2.mp4).
Here's the command. The resulting MKV file will contain two audio streams.
ffmpeg -i input_vid.mp4 -i input_aud_1.mp4 -i input_aud_2.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -c copy output.mkv


The command structure uses three input flags:
-i input_vid.mp4 -i input_aud_1.mp4 -i input_aud_2.mp4
These inputs are indexed as 0, 1, and 2 respectively.
-map 0:v: Use the video stream from the first input.
-map 1:a: Use the audio stream from the second input.
-map 2:a: Use the audio stream from the third input.

If you want the output duration to match the shortest input stream, you can add the `-shortest` option to the command. Otherwise, it will default to the length of the longest input.

There is a way, but it will require a small script.
You'll have to concatenate the audio before merging it with the video stream.
#!/bin/bash

prepare_audio() {
  mkdir -p temp_pcm && cd temp_pcm
  number=1
  find ../ -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname "*.ogg" -o -iname "*.wma" -o -iname "*.m4a" -o -iname "*.aac" -o -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.opus" \) | while read -r file; do
    filename=$(basename "${file%.*}")
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$file" "$number-$filename.wav"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Failed to convert $file to wav."
      exit 1
    fi
    number=$((number + 1))
  done

  ls --quoting-style=shell-always -1v *.wav > tmp.txt
  sed 's/^/file /' tmp.txt > list.txt && rm tmp.txt

  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -b:a 128k ../audio_muxed_final.aac
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Audio preparation failed."
    exit 1
  fi

  cd ..; rm -rf ./temp_pcm
}

container_to_mkv() {
  file=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.webm" -o -iname "*.wmv" -o -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.mov" -o -iname "*.m4v" \) -print -quit)
  if [ -z "$file" ]; then
    echo "No video file found."
    exit 1
  fi
  filename=$(basename "${file%.*}")
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$file" -an -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero "video_$filename.mkv"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to convert $file to mkv."
    exit 1
  fi
  video_track="video_$filename.mkv"
}

prepare_audio
container_to_mkv

ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$video_track" -i audio_muxed_final.aac -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -shortest final_mux.mkv && rm "$video_track" audio_muxed_final.aac

exit 0

Save as: multi_audio_mux.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x multi_audio_mux.sh
Usage: ./multi_audio_mux.sh
Just place the script in the directory with your audio files and video file, then run it!
